# how to update all the variable changes in the service to the $scope.var in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to update a variable in my controller every time a variable is updated in my service. I'm using the $scope.$watch(), but unfortunately only the last change is being effected. Here is the code that I used. Does anyone know what is wrong with this?
Service:

```
rApp.factory('pService', ['$http', '$rootScope', '$sanitize', 

function ($http, $rootScope, $sanitize) {

 var pService = {};

 //Some other code

 pService.Update=function(status)
 {
   if(status.LastItemId!=undefined)
   {
     pService.disItemId = status.LastItemId;
   }
 }

 //Some other code

return pService;

});

Controller:

rApp.controller('dController', ['$scope','$rootScope' 'pService' ,dispenseController]);

function dController($scope,$rootScope, pService) {

$scope.$watch(function () { return pService.disItemId }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal != oldVal) {
            $scope.lastItemId = pService.disItemId;
        }
    })

});
```

Comment: Could you show how pService.Update() is called? Watchers are executed in the digest cycle. Probably you need to fire it manually.

Comment: pService is an object.  If you want to observe one property being changed inside the object, you need to set the object equality parameter on the watch to true.  Here's a cool, short little video Ben Nadel did to demonstrate: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2566-scope-watch-vs-watchcollection-in-angularjs.htm.

Comment: @jme11 it's not the case, here the scalar pService.disItemId is observed.

Comment: @Magomogo  You got me... need to read the code... or maybe I need one more coffee today.  ;-)

Comment: @Magomogo Actually i'd just no recommend using $watch and $apply at all. Theses are reserved to some specific directive uses. You can in 90% of the time do what you want without using theses.

Answer (score 0):

### **In your specific case :**

You don't need to use $watch. Actually you don't have any use of $watch in standard angular application.

Just do this in your controller :

```
  $scope.lastItem = pService;
```

And then use the var like this :

```
  $scope.lastItem.disItemId;
```

This will always point to the updated disItemId.

### **Problem**

If you bind your var like this :

**Service**

```
[...]
service.serviceVar = 1;
return service
[...]
```

This will create a "1" var with a reference.

**Controller**

```
  [...]
  $scope.myvar = Service.serviceVar;
  [...]
```

This will bind $scope.myvar to the "1" reference.

If you do this in your service or in an other controller :

```
   service.serviceVar = 2;
```

You will create a new var "2" with a new reference and you will assign this reference to service.serviceVar. Badly all your old references to the old 1 var will not update.

**Solution**

To avoid that do it like this :

**Service**

```
[...]
service.servicevar = {};
service.servicevar.value = 1;
return service
[...]
```

You create an object with a new reference and assign it to servicevar. You create a var "1" and assign it to servicevar.value.

**Controller**

```
[...]
$scope.myvar = Service.servicevar;
[...]
```

You assign the servicevar reference to your scope var.

**view**

```
{{myvar.value}}
```

You can use the value by using the property of your var.

Updating the var doing this :

```
service.servicevar.value = 2;
```

You will create a new var "2" with a new reference and replace the old reference by this one.

BUT this time you keep all your references to servicevar in your controllers.

I hope i was clear and it solve you issue.

**EDIT**

My answer was only a partial answer on this question.

Here is the update [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hkZzYEIGuZGT19LDx0Kj?p=preview)

First you had a type on the controller definition. You're closing the braces too early. Here is the good definition

```
app.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope','pService',

function MainCtrl($scope,pService) {

  $scope.serviceVar=pService.myVar;
  $scope.val = $scope.serviceVar;  

}]);
```

Then you were using `windows.interval` in angular you need to use the `$interval` service instead

Example :

```
app.factory('pService',function($interval){

  var pService={};

  pService.myVar={};

  pService.myVar.count=1;

  $interval(function(){
    pService.myVar.count++;
  },1000);

  return pService;
});
```

Then my problem was occuring. You were binding the value instead of the object in your controller. It looks like this now :

```
  $scope.val = $scope.serviceVar;
```

Hope it helped you

Comment: thx for the response, but I unfortunately I don't see it working :( in my case.

Comment: @AjaySrikanth Could you add a plunker of your behaviour ? I'll make it work

Comment: @AjaySrikanth There were some major problems here is the edited plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/hkZzYEIGuZGT19LDx0Kj?p=preview i'll edit my answer

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I'm just curious to know the difference between $scope.val = $scope.serviceVar; and $scope.val = $scope.serviceVar.count; I see the first one works and the second one doesn't.

Comment: @AjaySrikanth juste re-read my answer. I explained the différence between binding to a primitive var or an object. Dunno if it was clear, but that was what i explained. That's juste some references tricks.

Comment: @AjaySrikanth If this answer your question, think about making the post as the answer :). If you got anymore question feel free to ask